# Why cbind for ts objects behaves different from cbind for matrices and data.frames in R?

Tags: r

Does anyone why the result of the following code is different?

```
a <- cbind(1:10,1:10)
b <- a
colnames(a) <- c("a","b")
colnames(b) <- c("c","d")

colnames(cbind(a,b))
> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
colnames(cbind(ts(a),ts(b)))
> [1] "ts(a).a" "ts(a).b" "ts(b).c" "ts(b).d"
```

Is this or compatibility reasons? Cbind for xts and zoo does not have this feature.

I always accepted this as given, but now my code is littered with the following:

```
ca<-colnames(a)
cb<-colnames(b)
out <- cbind(a,b)
colnames(out) <- c(ca,cb)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just what the `cbind.ts` method does. You can see the relevant code via `stats:::cbind.ts`, `stats:::.cbind.ts`, and `stats:::.makeNamesTs`.

I can't explain why it was made to be different, since I didn't write it, but here's a work-around.

```
cbts <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  ists <- sapply(dots,is.ts)
  if(!all(ists)) stop("argument ", which(!ists), " is not a ts object")
  do.call(cbind,unlist(lapply(dots,as.list),recursive=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: This will give interesting results if tseries library is not loaded :)

Comment: @mpiktas: Oddly enough, it worked fine for me without loading tseries, as long as xts was loaded... but doesn't work in a clean R session.

Comment: Yes, I've been bitten by this feature recently. Spent an hour investigating why. When tseries is not loaded as.list(x) works like as.list(as.numeric(x)).

Comment: @mpiktas: that's easily solved by adding `stopifnot(require(tseries))` to the first line of the function.

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer something along the lines ```cbts <- function(...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    cnames <- unlist(lapply(dots,function(l){
        if(is.null(dim(l)))""
        else colnames(l)
        
    }))
    out <- do.call("cbind",dots)
    colnames(out) <- cnames
    out
}```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're interested in *why* this happens.

Taking a look at the body of `stats:::.cbind.ts`, which is the function that does column binding for time series, shows that naming is performed by `.makeNamesTs`. Taking a look at `stats:::.make.Names.Ts` reveals that the names are derived directly from the arguments you pass to `cbind`, and there is no obvious way to influence this. As an example, try:

```
cbind(ts(a),ts(b, start = 2))
```

You will find that the `start` specification of the second time series appears in the name of the respective columns.

As to *why* that's the way things are ... I can't help you there!

Comment: I looked at he code, before asking the question. To get the current behaviour actually takes more effort than simply dumping concatenated names of original arguments.

Comment: Looking at `merge.zoo`, which is what `cbind.zoo` uses, it certainly doesn't take the easy route, like you suggest. Perhaps there's a reason for that somewhere. Interesting behaviour, regardless.